# OCMock [OCMAnyConstraint isProxy]: message sent to deallocated instance, what's happening?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, reactive-cocoa, ocmock

I'm attempting to do a straightforward mock of an object,

```
HTAppleWatchDevice * shared = [[HTAppleWatchDevice alloc] init];
id watchMock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:shared];
[deviceManager setAppleWatchDevice:watchMock];

void (^replyDict)(NSDictionary*) = ^void(NSDictionary* response){};

[[watchMock expect] dataReturnedFromServer:[OCMArg isNotNil] ofType:[OCMArg any]];
[watchMock handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:request reply:replyDict];
[watchMock verifyWithDelay:10];
```

Indeed the expected method is called, but I get this sort of error, depending on the second OCMArg:

> [OCMAnyConstraint isProxy]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7f954608b630

I've literally tried putting the expected call FIRST in handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:, with dummy data, but the exact same error occurs.

```
[self dataReturnedFromServer:@[] ofType:[self supportedMIMETypes].firstObject];
```

Update: The class utilizes reactive cocoa, which swaps the object's class, I suspect there could be an interaction happening due to overlapping class swapping. I'm gonna tag it, until I count it out.

Case in point, I comment-out the verify line

```
[[watchMock expect] dataReturnedFromServer:[OCMArg isNotNil] ofType:[OCMArg any]];
[watchMock handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:request reply:replyDict];
//[watchMock verifyWithDelay:10];
```

but another exception comes up, once the previous watchMock is dealloc'd:

> RACKVOTrampoline.m:dispose method, exception, upon next test start…:

```
[target removeObserver:RACKVOProxy.sharedProxy forKeyPath:self.keyPath context:(__bridge void *)self];
```

> error: -[HTAppleWatchDeviceTest nameOfNextTest] : failed: caught "NSRangeException", "Cannot remove an observer  for the key path "delegate" from  because it is not registered as an observer."

Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? Often problems with testing your code indicate that your design could be improved. For example, you call a method (`handleWatchKitExtensionRequest`) on your mock object instead of calling it on the tested object - why is that?

Comment: In this case I thought that was the appropriate methodology, with watchMock being a partial mock. If I don't set deviceManager's appleWatchDevice to be my partialMock, then the partial mock never gets called. (it is a new object, after all)
Is that what you mean? Or should I be calling on the original object, if so, why?

Comment: partial mocking will 1) change the class of the mocked object, such that mocked methods (or with OCMock 3, most every method) get overridden to forward back to the mock, and 2) sets up the mock object to forward methods back to the real object if appropriate.  So, normally you should be able to pass either the mock instance or the original instance into methods -- in some cases passing the original may work better.

Comment: Also, OCMock can have issues with code which also change the object's class (like KVObserving), so that is a potential issue as well.  You may need to call stopMocking to restore the original, pre-mock class before allowing any KVO stuff to be removed.   Or, if KVO is done after the partial mock is created, make sure the KVO is un-done before the mock is dealloced (or you call stopMocking).

Answer (score 1):

Well, let me show a workaround I figured-out through Method Swizzling– although I'm not going to accept it.

> HTAppleWatchDeviceTest.m

```
static XCTestExpectation* roundTripExpectation = nil; //static var is avail from this FILE

-(void) testPerceiveActuateRoundTrip{
roundTripExpectation = [self expectationWithDescription:@"should return data"];
HTAppleWatchDevice * shared = [deviceManager appleWatchDevice];

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    //steps
    //1 identify old and new selectors
    SEL oldSelector = @selector(dataReturnedFromServer:ofType:);
    SEL newSelector = @selector(HTTest_dataReturnedFromServer:ofType:);
    //2 get old method for old selector
    Method oldMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([shared class], oldSelector);
    //3 get new implementation for new selector
    Method newMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], newSelector);
    //4 set new implementation for old selector -- might fail
    BOOL addedFine = class_addMethod([shared class], oldSelector, method_getImplementation(newMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(newMethod));
    //5 set old implementation for new selector, used to continue normal execution
    class_addMethod([shared class], newSelector, method_getImplementation(oldMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(oldMethod));
    //6 swap new and old implementations for HTAppleWatchDevice, if not already set above
    //NOTE: will NOT effect step 5, as implementation was set directly. WILL effect [self HTTest_dataReturnedFromServer:ofType:] -> oldImplementation (on HTAppleWatchDevice), but NBD
    if (!addedFine){
        method_exchangeImplementations(oldMethod, newMethod);
    }
});

void (^replyDict)(NSDictionary*) = ^void(NSDictionary* response){};
[shared handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:request reply:replyDict];
[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:10 handler:nil];
roundTripExpectation = nil;
}

//this method will ONLY be called with [self class] == HTAppleWatchDevice
-(void)HTTest_dataReturnedFromServer:(NSArray*)activations ofType:(NSString*)type{
[self HTTest_dataReturnedFromServer:activations ofType:type];
[testPerceiveActuateRoundTripExpectation fulfill];
}
```